# Function JS can't append in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I create a JavaScript function to append HTML, but I can't display it. 
I created an array on my HTML, and I would like add row with my function. 
And, I created an ajax request, to get my images.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 grid-flow-col gap-1">
  <div class="images-array"></div>
</div>
```

AJAX Request:

```
var urlPost = "assets/js/imgStock.json"
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlPost,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            createPostItem(value.name, value.image, value.madeFor, value.size);
        });
    }
});
```

Function "createPostItem" to add HTML:

```
function createPostItem(name, image, madeFor, size) {
    var RowsNumber;
    if (size == 'story') {
        RowsNumber = 'span 2 / span 2';
    } else {
        RowsNumber = 'span 1 / span 1';
    }

    var html = '<div style="grid-row: ' + RowsNumber + ';">' +
        '<div class="flex text-gray-200 animate__animated animate__fadeIn">' +
        '<div class="mx-auto transition duration-300 ease-in transform hover:-translate-y-2">' +
        '<img class="block shadow-2xl" src="' + image + '" alt="' + name + '"' +
        '<div class="absolute">' +
        '<div class="absolute btn-i text-center pt-2">' + name + '</div>' +
        '<span class="flex absolute font-semibold tracking-wide justify-center absolute-pill px-1 text-xxs bg-yellow-400 text-gray-900 rounded-full text-xs">' + madeFor + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      $(".images-array").append(html);
    }
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Calendrier Sofiane Boufal",
    "image": "img/Boufal_Story.jpg",
    "size": "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cover fictive rap",
    "image": "img/Roshi_Cover.jpg",
    "size": "post",
    "madeFor": "Captain Roshi",
  },
  {
    "name": "Visuel promotionnel Instagram",
    "image": "img/Post-Instagram-Edi.jpg",
    "size": "post",
    "madeFor": "Edi Kuka",
  },
  {
    "name": "Calendrier Jean-Pierre Nsame",
    "image": "img/mars_nsame.jpg",
    "size":  "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anniveraire Houboulang Mendes",
    "image": "img/Mendes-Birthday.jpg",
    "size":  "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: nothing , it's unbearable :@

Comment: can you post `data` op as well in your question?

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in `var RowsNumber;` and see if the browser even gets to it..

Comment: Breakpoint is console.log ? x.x" sorry

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Add logging to find where where, exactly, it breaks.

Comment: Similar in term that it's used for debugging, but no. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints